# 検索エンジンなどのロボットを判定するPythonモジュールはありますか？

Tags: python

とある処理で検索エンジンなどのロボットを判定する必要があり、Pythonモジュールを探しています。

User-Agent文字列もしくは、WSGIのrequestを渡すことでロボットかどうか判定してくれるモジュールがもしあれば教えてください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[woothee-python](https://github.com/woothee/woothee-python) というものがあります。

特徴は以下の通りです。

- User-Agent のデータセットは [GitHub](https://github.com/woothee/woothee) 上で継続的にメンテナンスされている
- 同一データセットを用いた同様のライブラリが[多言語](https://github.com/woothee)で用意されている

クローラの判定については以下のようにできます。

```python
woothee.is_crawler('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0)')
// => False
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
クローラー判定もバッチリだったので、今回はこちらの woothee を利用させてもらいました。

pip に登録されていると最高ですね。

Comment: PyPI にも登録されたようです https://pypi.python.org/pypi/woothee/

Answer (score 3):

「ズバリそのもの」のモジュールがあります → [`robot-detection`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robot-detection)
下記のサンプルコードにあるように、 User-Agent 文字列によってロボット判定が行われます。

```
>>> import robot_detection
>>> robot_detection.is_robot(user_agent_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

python-user-agents(https://github.com/selwin/python-user-agents)
の ‘is_bot‘ で判別できると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
こちらを試したのですが、デバイスリストにgooglebot_mobileしか定義されておらず、今回の用途では使えなそうでした。

https://github.com/selwin/python-user-agents/blob/master/user_agents/devices.json